# Parallax css background image move a little

Tags: html, image, css, parallax

I have my background image from `background-url` and my parallax works for the image when I put: `background-attachment: fixed;`

How can I make it so that the background image moves a little bit when I scroll?

Here is the examples I'm talking about:

This is what I have now when I scroll: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm

This is what I want when I scroll:
http://materializecss.com/parallax-demo.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [this link](http://callmenick.com/post/advanced-parallax-scrolling-effect) will help it uses Javascript to move the background image

## EDIT

I just realized this only works because the background image is a repeating pattern. If you want to do this effect with a normal image you can use [Parallax.js](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of CSS3's `transform` and `transition` properties to make the background image animate. Here is a [link](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F0YFLW4TQSB3) to how to do that. You can use Javascript's `onscroll` event to trigger what I have triggered on hover.

#### Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    div {
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: yellow;
      border: 1px solid black;
      transition: all 2s;
    }
    
    div:hover {
      -ms-transform: translate(0px, 100px);
      /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 100px);
      /* Safari */
      transform: translate(0px, 100px);
      /* Standard syntax */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    Set this css on background image of your element. Use javascript to transform on scroll.
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```